# Wrong Answers for Matching Algorithm [Java]

Tags: java, matching

I've come across this matching algorithm which finds patterns in integer arrays. It takes one array s, which has the sequence which to do the matching in. And another array with a pattern p, which has the pattern to match.

```
// Example: Match {1, 2} in {1, 3, 1, 2, 3} =>
// after finding the first 3, skips ahead to the second 1, then finds {1, 2} at 2.
public static int match2(final int[] s, final int[] p) {
 for (int i = 0; i <= s.length - p.length; i++) {
   int j;
   for (j = 0; j < p.length; j++) {
     if (t[i + j] != p[j]) {
     i += j; // Mismatch, skip ahead.
     break;
     }
   }
   if (j == p.length) {
 return i;
 }
}
return -1;
}
```

Is there any input that can make this piece of code give out a faulty output?

Comment: does a NullPointerException count as "faulty output"? Because that is easy: just pass null into the function instead of arrays.

Comment: does `t[i + j]` means `s[i + j]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot find {1,2} in {1,1,2}.